# How to combine plots generated within a loop as subplots in one larger figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have code that builds graphs in a loop one after the other. But they are inconvenient to analyze. I would like to build graphs of two in a row. How do I change the code?

```
for cat in test.category_doubled.unique():
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
    y = test.best_channels[test.category_doubled == cat].values
    plt.scatter(
        test.signal[test.category_doubled == cat].values,
        test['shift'][test.category_doubled == cat].values,
        c=y,
        s=20,
        label=f'cat_num:_{cat}___claster_num:_{len(np.unique(y))}'
    )
    plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated code according to OP's comment below.

You can set up subplots in one figure of `n` rows with two subplots per row with `plt.subplot(n, 2, i)`, where `i` is the subplot counter. So for one figure with 6 x 2 subplots, we can do this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 35] 

for idx, cat in enumerate(test.category_doubled.unique()): 

    plt.subplot(6, 2, idx + 1) 

    y = test.best_channels[test.category_doubled == cat].values 
    plt.scatter(
        test.signal[test.category_doubled == cat].values, 
        test['shift'][test.category_doubled == cat].values, 
        c=y, s=20, 
        label=f'cat_num:_{cat}___claster_num:_{len(np.unique(y))}' 
    ) 
    plt.legend()
```

Comment: I modified your code because it only displayed one row with two graphs. `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 35]
for idx, cat in enumerate(test.category_doubled.unique()):
    plt.subplot(6,2,idx+1)
    y = test.best_channels[test.category_doubled == cat].values
    plt.scatter(
        test.signal[test.category_doubled == cat].values,
        test['shift'][test.category_doubled == cat].values,
        c=y,
        s=20,
        label=f'cat_num:_{cat}___claster_num:_{len(np.unique(y))}'
    )
    plt.legend()`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll put this in the answer.